# How to override stock availability in product detail page without overriding the template Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

I am using Magento 2.4.2 version. I like to know if there is any possibility to override the stock status on the product detail page without overriding the template. Please help and Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Hello. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you only want to change stock status from Instock to Outofstock? OR if you want to change the verbiage then you have to make change in template file OR another work around is you can use translation but that will not be conditional. Let me know if you need any other help.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

On your etc\di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="hidecartbutton" type="vendor\module\Plugin\HideAddButtonOutOfStock" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
```

Create a Plugins folder an add the file **HideAddButtonOutOfStock.php**

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Plugin;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

class HideAddButtonOutOfStock
{

    protected $_session;
    protected $productRepository;
    public function __construct(
        Session                                     $session,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository    $productRepository     
    ) 
    {
        $this->_session           = $session;
        $this->productRepository  = $productRepository;
    }
    
   public function afterIsAvailable( Product $product)
   {
            $hasStock = //place your condition here

       
            if ($hasStock)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
       
    }
}

?>
```